# Incorrect source maps

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, browser

Im building a react project from scratch using babel with the following configuration:

```
**Babel**:
const path = require('path');
module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: '/frontend/src/index.tsx',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'frontend/dist'),
    filename: 'main.js',
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        loader: 'ts-loader',
        exclude: '/node_modules',
      },
      {
        test: /.tsx$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /.(png|jpg|jpeg|svg)$/,
        use: 'file-loader',
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['tsx'],
  },
};



Typescript:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
  "outDir": "./frontend/dist",
  "rootDir": "./frontend/src",
  "sourceMap": true,
  "module": "ES6",
  "target": "ES5",
  "jsx": "preserve",
  "esModuleInterop": true
},
"include": ["./frontend/src/**/*.tsx"]
}
```

I want to be able to dubug my code in browser with the help of `source maps` but for some reason im not getting the clean source code.

My source code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';

const O = () => {
  return <button>Click</button>;
};

const root = createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));

root.render(<O />);
```

Source map in browser chrome@latest:

```
import React from 'react';
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';

const O = () => {
  return /*#__PURE__*/React.createElement("button", null, "Click");
};

const root = createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render( /*#__PURE__*/React.createElement(O, null));
```

So, my question is, can the browser show me the exact source code i have in my text editor?

Comment: I also should mention that my source code extension is `.tsx` and that code written in `.jsx` gives me the expected result

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be able to debug your original source then you can thanks to the magic of sourcemaps. There are 2 steps to getting this set up with ts-loader and webpack.

First, for ts-loader to produce sourcemaps, you will need to set the tsconfig.json option as "sourceMap": true.

https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader#devtool--sourcemaps

Answer (score 1):

when you are using ts-loader

tsconfig.json

```json
"compilerOptions": {
  "sourceMap": true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution was passing the code to compilers in the correct order: First `babel-loader`, then `ts-loader`.

Had to change my webpack config:

```
const path = require('path');
module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: '/frontend/src/index.tsx',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'frontend/dist'),
    filename: 'main.js',
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx$/,
        use: ['babel-loader', 'ts-loader'],
        exclude: '/node_modules',
      },
      {
        test: /.(png|jpg|jpeg|svg)$/,
        use: 'file-loader',
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.tsx', '.jsx'],
  },
};
```